# How should one set cmake ar/ranlib

Tags: cmake

I'm using the following variables.  It seems cmake do use clang but ar/ranlib is not properly set.

```
//cmake version 3.18.2

SET(CMAKE_AR           ${tools}/bin/llvm-ar)
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB       ${tools}/bin/llvm-ranlib)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${tools}/bin/clang)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/clang++)
```

My attempt at an **reprex**:

checkout llvm-project 7fa503ef

```
$ mkdir clang1
# build clang here

$ cd <...>/llvm-project
$ cat ./my-toolchain.cmake

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(tools ./clang1)
SET(CMAKE_AR           ${tools}/bin/llvm-ar)
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB       ${tools}/bin/llvm-ranlib)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${tools}/bin/clang)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/clang++)


$ mkdir clang2; cd clang2
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../my-toolchain.cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
$ cat ./lib/Demangle/CMakeFiles/LLVMDemangle.dir/link.txt
```

Tried this from @Tsyvarev

```
SET(CMAKE_AR           ${tools}/bin/llvm-ar CACHE FILEPATH "ar")
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB       ${tools}/bin/llvm-ranlib CACHE FILEPATH "ranlib")
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/set.html

Still getting -- Wrong!

```
/usr/bin/ar
/usr/bin/ranlib
```

I'm sorry.  The trick did work!

Comment: "It seems cmake do use clang but ar/ranlib is not properly set." - How do you detect that CMake doesn't use the archiver? Where do you put the code you show? Please, prepare [mcve].

Comment: I looked at the `link.txt` file.  Seems `/usr/bin/ar` is being used.

Comment: Variables `CMAKE_AR` and `CMAKE_RANLIB` has an effect only when they are defined as CACHE'd. See the duplicate question for more info.

Comment: I'm still getting `/usr/bin/ar`.  By the way is it okay to use the `/usr/bin/ar` instead of `llvm-ar` with custom clang?

Comment: Have you tried clean reconfigure, with empty build directory or at least without `CMakeCache.txt` file in it? Also, using *relative* path for `tools` variable, which is used for compiler/archiver/etc., is a wrong way. All path-like variables in CMake should be set to **absolute** paths.

Comment: It works now! Not sure what I did wrong previously though.